# Indexing and searching nested documents in Solr 8.2

Tags: solr, nested-documents

I have followed the example given in https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_2/searching-nested-documents.html#child-doc-transformer. I have *_nest_path_* and *_root_* fields in my schema.

I want to index nested documents and search over the nested documents. The above link has an example to filter out children matching a particular filter using ChildDocTransformer but it does not return the same result after I tried.

Comment: So what did you try (what was your query?), what does your documents look like and what is the result you expects from that query?

Comment: I tried the query from the documentation link. I basically replicated the example. Indexed two documents and tried to fetch the documents in nested structure using ChildDocTransformer but that didn't work.

Comment: did this work for you, i want to implement nested documents

Comment: No. I had to drop it for time being.